# System load vs user load

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rhq

I found two options in my dashboard like system load and user load.
What is the difference between them and which one should be monitored .

I am using JON 3.3 to monitor EAP applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RHQ/JON, user load metric is the measured percentage CPU utilization in user code (code executed in user space). System load is the measured percentage for system code (kernel code).

Both measures are useful and should be monitored. They give you a better view of how CPU usage is spent on your system (as opposed to a global CPU usage percentage).